# How to embed a font in a webpage in a secure read-only mode?

Tags: web, fonts, webfonts

I want to use this font, Luthier, for the main title of a Wordpress-based website.

The font’s license allows web-embedding only in a secure, read-only mode. I don’t know how to apply this read-only mode to the code, nor did I find reference of how to do it after searching the web.

Here’s the license item in question:

> 4_Embedding of the fonts into web pages or digital documents is
>   permitted only in a secured, read-only mode

PS: If this should be in the GraphicDesign community, my apologies, please delete this question. Thanks.

Comment: I guess there is a way to encrypt the CSS font-face property where use can only see the font but can't access woff or TTF.

Comment: @MoxetKhan I don’t see it listed here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp but, I’m new with this stuff, so... maybe it’s me who doesn’t get it.

Comment: please have look to this article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6523498/how-to-protect-webfonts